# Azure nodejs web app custom domain subdirectory to another azure web app(blog)

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, dns, cross-domain

I have simple Node.js Webapp with custom domain ex: domain.com.
I have created another azure cloudapp from bitnami and mapped it to blog.domain.com

Now, I would like to have a blog path domain.com/blog which should serve the blog from blog.domain.com

As I researched, I have added a blog route in **server.js** and a rule in my **web.config** 
but its not working.

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/',(req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname +  '/public/index.html'));
});

router.get('/blog',(req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/blog.html'));
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/', router);

app.listen(port);
```

Web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <!-- <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule> -->
        <rule name="blogRedirect" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true"> 
            <match url="^blog" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://mathan.azurewebsites.net/hello" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Can someone guide me what's wrong with the things I did?

Comment: you could set the URL rewrite rule for the domain name `<rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^subfolder/(.*)" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.subfolder.domain.org/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>`

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I tried that.

```
<rule name="blogRedirect" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true"> 
            <match url="^blog" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://blog.mathan.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```
but its not working.

Comment: what error did you face?

Comment: there is no error at all. When i navigate to  mathan.com/blog. it stops there  "Cannot get /blog"

So I tried adding a blog route in nodejs , then when I navigate, it still shows blank page only. 

router.get('/blog',(req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/blog.html'));
});

Comment: did you try to run the failed request tracing?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Sorry, I don't know how to do that. how can I trace the web.config?

Comment: you could refer these links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis